# Работает ли boost с русскими буквами?

Tags: boost, c++, linux

Попробовал хваленый boost

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ()
{
    string str1(" яhelloй world! ");
    to_upper(str1);  // str1 == " HELLO WORLD! "
    trim(str1);      // str1 == "HELLO WORLD!"

    string str2=
       to_lower_copy(
          ireplace_first_copy(
             str1,"hello","goodbye")); // str2 == "goodbye world!"
    cout << str1 << "   "  << str2 <<'\n';
}
```

компилирую, запускаю

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ tboost3.cpp 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
яHELLOй WORLD!   яgoodbyeй world!
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Вопрос, собственно простой, а как заставить boost применять свои алгоритмы к русским буквам?

Comment: Там, где развернулось сейчас обсуждение (ответ @Dith), у меня комментарии закончились.

Насколько смог разобраться у меня (в Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS) скачался (совсем недавно apt-get-ом) boost 1.40

Очевидно поэтому и не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй `wstring` и, соответственно, `wcout;` при этом придется установить локаль. `string algo` хорошо кушает `wstring`, `to_upper` работает (пробовал).

Comment: Понял. Т.е. setlocale(LC_ALL,""):

А все остальное в нем также хорошо воспринимает wstring вместо string?

И что произойдет при чтении из файла символа не из кодировки? Перестанет читать, как и fgetwc()?

Comment: Лучше писать 

    #include <locale>
    locale::global (locale(""));

Comment: Вроде бы да, все функции работают с wstring нормально, но можно проверить.

Comment: По моему мнению, нету вообще никакого резона работать _не_ с wstring (кроме случаев чтения входных данных, но тут их надо срочно переконвертировать в wstring и забыть о проблемах). Зависеть от системной кодовой страницы как-то уж совсем неправильно.

Comment: @mikillskegg, СПАСИБО! 

Добрался до компа, проверил - ОК.

Для locale::global (locale("")) важна установка LC_CTYPE в русскую кодировку, а для locale::global (locale("ru_RU.utf8")) все равно, использует русский.

Comment: wstring не панацея, достаточно использовать _правильную_локаль_ и _правильную_кодировку_литералов_в_исходнике_. Никогда не задумывались что 'Я' может быть равно '\xDF' или 'xF1' или вообще?
Использовать wstring c UTF-8 вообще бессмысленно.

Comment: @Dith, см. теги. Вопрос про Линукс, а Вы не задумывались, что в Линуксе тотально используется UTF-8, так что в нем для работы с кириллицей без wchar_t не обойтись?

Comment: @Dith, а в самом деле, причем здесь кодировка байта в KOI8-R?

Вообще-то я надеялся, что boost "достаточно продвинут", чтобы автоматически

1) правильно определять кодировку во время трансляции

2) правильно перекодировать текст ввода-вывода в зависимости от текущей  локализации во время исполнения

Но, похоже это не так.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Вы это об чём? или обком? Где utf-8, а где wchar_t?  @Dith пытался намекнуть на разницу между wide char и multibyte sequence. Уточняющий вопрос: сколько в Ваших программах вызовов mbtowc и wctomb (или им родственных).

Comment: О мой бедный мозг. Дайте ФАК по работе со всеми этими с**** локалями в средах linux и windows. Желательно с историческим экскурсом почему получилось именно так, а не иначе.

Comment: @alexlz, а как еще можно стандартными средствами С++ работать с многобайтовыми символами юникода? Без wchar_t тут, увы, не обойтись. В С++11 вроде бы сделали какие-то более кошерные средства для работы непосредственно с юникодом, но пока еще до них не дошел.

Comment: @gecube, какие локали интересуют - системные или как компонент С++ ?

Comment: раз пошла такая пьянка
http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/info/FAQ.winapi.ManySidedUnicode
При работе со строками нужно четко различать, где какая кодировка:
1. Во внешних источниках (файлы, бд, сеть)
2. Строковые и символьные литералы.
3. Строки во время исполнения, при работе с более чем одно кодировкой (файлы в utf8 и юникодная версия WinAPI, например)

Comment: @mikillskegg utf8 на большинстве _десктопных_ линуксов не означает на большинстве вообще. Для работы с кириллицей сойдет и обычные char, потому как это хранилище, а не способ кодирования и в отличие от wchar_t сохранит преимущества utf8 при хранении латинских символов.

Comment: @avp 
1) правильно указать кодировку - задача программиста, работающего с не-дефольным набором символов  (грубо говоря с не латиницей), то что вы предлагаете для буста, задача сколь интересная столь и бессмысленная. 
2) Правильная перекодировка текста ввода/вывода происходит при правильной установки локали же.

Comment: @Dith "юникодная версия WinAPI" -- как мне здесь объяснили -- это очень красивый прикол. И ucs-2 -- юникод, и utf-16 -- тоже юникод.

Comment: @Dith: Почему не панацея? Если вы после чтения данных _всегда_ тут же перекодируете их в utf-16 и храните в `wstring`, всё прекрасно работает без дополнительного геморроя. Плюс от вас уходят проблемы с например `strlen`, навсегда. Проблема с кодировкой символов _в исходниках_ -- совершенно отдельный вопрос, и я с удовольствием опять-таки использую для исходников unicode. MSVC поддерживает "из коробки", gcc хочет ключи `-finput-charset` и кажется `-fwide-exec-charset`.

Comment: @VladD Я уже писал, что фокус с трансформацией ucs-2 в utf-16 в виндах (и, кажется, в java) мне кажется весьма прикольным. С utf8 всё просто -- код 128 и выше -- не латинский алфавит и, следовательно несколько байт. Как определить, где ucs-2 совпадает с utf-16? Кстати, wchar и 2 байта д.б. разные длины.

Comment: @alexlz: определить очень просто: каждый символ ucs-2 определён и в utf-16, и они совпадают по числовому значению, причём это значение умещается в 2 байта. ([Пруф](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B0000_to_U.2BD7FF_and_U.2BE000_to_U.2BFFFF).) Мне кажется, вряд ли кому-либо придётся обрабатывать данные вне Basic Multilingual Plane, так что виндовые ucs-16 (если я не ошибаюсь, функции типа length для wstring исходят именно из формата ucs-2) тоже вполне подходят.

Comment: @Dith "Мне кажется, вряд ли кому-либо придётся обрабатывать данные вне Basic Multilingual Plane"

Мне -- вряд ли. Но один мой знакомый, устроившись в одну фирму (в нашем городе, достаточно небольшом) был направлен на год или два в Ю.Корею. Приходилось ли ему там иметь дело с иероглифами или нет -- я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

По вежливой просьбе [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) привожу ответ, без использования wchar_t

первое и самое простое - раширенная ANSII кодировка:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ()
{
    //моя старая добрая слака в кошерной кодировке
    std::locale::global(std::locale(".KOI8-R"));
    string str1(" яhelloй world! ");
    to_upper(str1);
    trim(str1);

    string str2=
       to_lower_copy(
          ireplace_first_copy(
             str1,"hello", "goodbye"));
    cout << str1 << "   "  << str2 <<'\n';
}
```

модифицирующе алгортимы берут фацет из глобального контекста, и потому производят правильное case-преобразование

Вариант с wchar_t, тут еще проще
все символы у нас напрямую кодируются по таблице UCS-2.
Хочу заострить внимание на то, что кодировка будет не UTF-8, а UTF-16.

Теперь самая мякотка: utf-8
Теоретически можно установить глобальный контекс локализации в "ru_RU.UTF-8", и получить требуемое,
однако не практике выходит что в большинстве реализация отсутствует необходимый фацет. Насколько я знаю в STLPort он сеть, хотя работает только под линукс.
Но даже при этом затронутая тут тема case-преобразования будет работать неправильно. 
Почему? Потому-что в некоторых языках при преобразовании регистра появляются/удаляются новые символы! Это уже вопрос не кириллицы, а глобальной интернационализации.
char/wchar_t - это про способ хранения, а не про использование.

Потому самым правильным ответом на вопрос будет:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main ()
{
    locale::generator gen;         //<-- магия
    std::locale utf8Loc(gen(""));  //<-- тут

    string str1(" яhelloй world! ");
    str1 = locale::to_upper(str1, utf8Loc);
    trim(str1);

    string str2 =
        locale::to_lower(
            ireplace_first_copy(str1,"hello","goodbye"), 
            utf8Loc
        );
    cout << str1 << "   "  << str2 <<endl;
}
```

Хотя не исключено что и здесь могут быть огрехи.

---

UPD

windows.h в первом примере конечно не нужен, скопипастил не с того окна (fail)

Для второго примера нужен буст версии 1.48 и выше.

Comment: @Vlad возможно он прост в большем количестве случаев, но это потому что юникод. Представим ситуацию, скажем, когда у нас появились третестороние библиотеки которые вообще не понимают юникод, либо работают только с utf8. А если их несколько? Конвертировать придется постоянно, а тут уже разницы между char/wchar практически нет. Написать wchar_t может и решает текущую задачу, но не разрешает всей (потенциальной) проблемы.

Comment: @alexlz UCS-2 везде совпадает с UTF-16. Но эта и любая подобная фраза - бред. Потому - что UCS-2 это _таблица_ _с_ _кодами_ символов, а UTF-8/16 - это _способы_ _кодирования_. В UTF-8 символы занимают от 1 до 5 (6) байтов и код символа больше 127 не равен его коду в таблице, ибо различаются они по префиксам и т.д. (в википедии хорошая схема). В UTF-16 только 2 байта и потому оригинальные коды, потому и заменяют часто UTF-16 на UCS-2.

Comment: @Dith и в ucs-2 включается символ 0x1ffff (или подобные)? А в uft-16 -- 2 байта. Или два раза по 2 байта...

Comment: @Dith, не знаю где Вы гоняли свои примеры, но у меня 

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l

не работает.

Дело даже не в наличии <windows.h> и отсутствии <iostream>, а просто 

первый собирается и ...

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tboost3-1.cpp 
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    terminate called after throwing an instance of    'std::runtime_error'
    what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
    Aborted
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ locale
    LANG=ru_RU.utf8
    LANGUAGE=en
    LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.utf8"
    .. прод. след...

Comment: продолжение (конец первого и второй пример)

    ....
    LC_ALL=
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tboost3-2.cpp 
    tboost3-2.cpp:2:28: error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or  directory
    ....

правим, как можем,  но не поддается 

    ....
    tboost3-2.cpp:12: error: ‘generator’ is not a member of ‘std::locale’
    tboost3-2.cpp:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘gen’
    tboost3-2.cpp:13: error: ‘gen’ was not declared in this scope
    tboost3-2.cpp:16: error: ‘to_upper’ is not a member of ‘std::locale’
    tboost3-2.cpp:20: error: ‘to_lower’ is not a member of ‘std::locale’

Comment: @Dith, места в комментариях мало, их лимит ограничен. Поэтому, если дискуссия продолжится, то в **UPD** у меня в вопросе, а у Вас в ответе.

А также:
   
    sizeof(wchar_t) = 4 

и ее кодировка в x86 (x86-64) "ucs-4le" (это имя для iconv), а не UTF-16.

Хороша ли KOI-8R (в качестве однобайтной)? 

Дело вкуса. Лично я считаю, что оптимальной для \*nix является iso8859-5 (HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, ...), но она практически не используется в мире линукса.

--

Кстати, а довести свои примеры до работоспособного состояния сможете?

Comment: @alexlz http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14 - тут более точно, об идентичности и как изъяснтьяся верно.
@avp Windows 00/03/XP/2008/7, Ubuntu 11.10/12.10, Debian 6. Интересно, что там у Вас в исходнике такое, пример выше требует линковки с libboost_local. Версию буста в студию.
------
Увидел добавку - буст нужно поновее, локали там вроде с 1.47 или 1.48
sizeof(wchar_t) - implementation defined, utf16(ucs2) - 2 байта, либо utf32(ucs4) - 4 байта. Моя вина что не упомянул этого сразу, но тут нюансов столько, что впору писать маленькую книжку про юникоды и С++.

Comment: @alexlz у себя в городе, тоже оочень небольшом и удаленном, приходилось заниматься национальным языком. Там как раз встретились все прелести юникодов.

Comment: @Dith, вот насчет книжки - это правильно.

--

Версия boost - а как ее посмотреть? Качнул недавно apt-get-ом,  а что именно, не запомнил. (надеялся, что boost позволит легко и естественно работать с русским в utf-8, но похоже, зря. Останусь (это и к лучшему) в Си)

--

Интересно, если требует линковки, то почему собралась?

--

Вообще-то лучше всегда ориентироваться не на последние версии, а на что-нибудь устоявшееся.

Comment: @Dith Если язык не входит в BMP, то о чём же Ваш утверждение. (Вопрос риторический -- тут уже комментариев выше крыши).

Comment: @Dith, спасибо за наводку на boost::locale: никогда не имел с нею дела, теперь буду знать. 

Однако, вопрос Вы все-таки обошли стороной, поскольку @avp его поставил конкретно про boost::string_algo, а Вы привлекли другую библиотеку )) 

Но все равно спасибо

@avp, Xubuntu 12.04 -  код собрался с бустом из репозитория (1.48)