# strcmp не хочет сравнивать строки

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <cstdio>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    int i;
    char numbers[][81] = { "Санёк", "24567", "Брат", "23145", "Мама", "25674", "Папа", "26475", "Любимая", "24534"}, name[81];
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    cin >> name;
    for (i=0; i<=10; i+=2)
    {
        if (!strcmp(name,numbers[i]))
        {
            cout << "Телефон " << name << ": " << numbers[i+1] << "\n";
            break;
        }
        if (i == 10)
        {
            cout << "Ничего не найдено\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Результат: http://smotr.im/assa

Почему так происходит?

P.S. Я только начал изучать C++.

Comment: Судя по алгоритму и программируете тоже недолго?

Comment: Это пример из учебника.

Comment: Задумайтесь над этой строчкой

    for (i=10; i<=10; i+=2)


Comment: Тема, здесь постоянно всплывающая -- виндовая консоль (cp866, а в программе cp1251). Для проверки выведите на cout массив numbers.

Comment: Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Рекомендую Вам как начинающему пока забыть про эти проблемы и использовать в программах только латиницу. При достижении определенного уровня знаний к этому вопросу можно будет вернуться.

Comment: Видимо так и сделаю. Очень жаль, что в учебниках об этом не предупреждают и используют кириллицу как ни в чём не бывало.

Comment: просто одни делают профессиональные учебники для начинающих, а другие самоучители(за 21 день!) для профессионалов. а у нас ещё к этому делу добавляются криворукие переводчики :(

Comment: и в данном случае беда не в кирилице... а в кодировке (то каким числом какая буква записывается) при вводе у тебя "Я" == 10 а при чтении "Я" == 23 можно научить программу правильно переводить но этому ты позже научишся... а пока используй сетлокале для вывода cout << "Телефон ": и тому подобного

Comment: Зря я на консоль подумал. Там ведь высветилось "введите имя". Но данная программа у меня в ubuntu брата нашла без проблем.

Comment: В ubuntu может быть, но вероятно у ТС виндовс, а там "Russian" это 1251, а в консоли 866, отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: @Mirdin Это что, ввод с клавиатуры в одной кодировке, вывод на экран -- в другой. Не верю. На скриншоте видно "Введите имя", а не крякозябры.

Comment: @alexlz  Кодировка "Russian" которую устанавливает ТС - это 1251, строковые литералы которые он использует тоже в ней, а ввод/вывод в консоли 866. Просто кодировка окон и консоли в виндовс разная, в отличие от линукса.

Comment: @Dith, у меня комментарии к Вашему ответу кончились. Здесь же лимит - 4 шт.  Вы пишете:

    @avp Вы уверенны, что это девственная консоль?
    ... то перед установкой свойств консоли нужно сначала получить её текущие свойства, и уже в зависимости от них устанавливать шрифты/локали. Может все-же сфокусироваться на принципах, которые я хотел передать?

Насчет девственности - нет, не уверен. Тем правильней Ваше замечание об получении ее свойств.

По поводу принципов: отлично, но только если это работает. 

Совет ТС. Учитесь в линуксе.  Намучиться с виндой еще успеете.

Comment: @Mirdin Ешё раз. Есть скриншот. Где видно, что выводится подсказка "Введите имя". Вводится имя "Брат", отображается нормально. Какая это кодировка -- сказать трудно. Но то, что она совпадает с кодировкой текстовых констант -- очевидно.

Comment: @alexlz, действительно странный скриншот. Я попробовал у себя программу ТС - кракозябры (как и ожидалось).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я погляжу народ тут совсем учиться не желает, и живет wchar_t фобиями, гадая на кофейной гуще.

Повторюсь [еще раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/176245/c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-boost-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) - необходимо четко различать в какой кодировке находятся ваши символы и строки:

1. Символьные и строковые литералы будут иметь туже кодировку, что и файл.
2. Внешние источники данных (БД, файлы, сеть и т.д.) - нужно указывать соответствующую кодировку и/или производить конвертацию вручную при необходимости.
3. Строки во время выполнения - при работе со сторонними библиотеками, использующих различную кодировку либо вообще не умеющей ей пользоваться.

По сабжу: разберем пример попроще, чтобы узнать где чего

```
//целевая система - windows, ибо у ТС вендовая консоль на скриншоте
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //строка в кодировке CP1251, дефолтной для текстовых файлов в венде
    const char* iName = "Санёк"; 
    char oName[6];

    //выводим сиволы в кодировке СP1251
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    //получаем крякозяблы, ибо консоль в кодировке DOS 866

    //вводим с консоли в той-же кодировке
    cin >> oName;

    //сравниваем строки побайтно, получаем фигню
    cout <<strcmp(iName, oName)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

что мы можем/должны сделать

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //строка в кодировке CP1251, дефолтной для текстовых файлов в венде
        const char* iName = "Санёк"; 
        char oName[6];

        //чтобы вывести нормальный текст
        //1. либо устанавливаем локаль для рантайма
        //setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian_russia.1251"); //1
        //2. либо устанавливаем нужную кодовую страницу для консоли
        //SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); //2

        cout << "Введите имя: ";

        //3. чтобы ввести в корректной кодировке, ставим кодовую страницу для ввода
        //SetConsoleCP(1251); //3
        cin >> oName;

        //сравниваем строки побайтно
        cout <<strcmp(iName, oName)<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

PS. для изучения с нуля С++ как первого языка рекомендуемую учебник Липпмана.

PPS. Курим 14 главу Джосаттиса и [вот этот фак](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/info/FAQ.winapi.ManySidedUnicode)

Comment: При этом **не забываем** переключить шрифт в консольном окошке на "Lucida Console". 

А вот как сделать это *программно* (и можно ли вообще) не знаю.

P.S. На своем компьютере эту операцию можно сделать один раз и запомнить шрифт для последующих вызовов консоли.

--

Если для консольных программ делать так, как Вы рекомендуете, то замучаетесь рассказывать пользователям, как работать с программой.

Некрасиво, но надежно, тупо перекодировать весь ввод-вывод консоли между cp866 и cp1251 (CharToOem(source_cp1251_str, output_cp866_str) и обратная ей OemToChar(input_cp866_str, working_cp1251_str)).

Comment: интересно, как заголовок <windows.h> заработает в Linux, ну или в кокой-то другой системе/компиляторе?

Comment: @Mirdin, можно дать советы про \#ifdef и т.п., но в реальности кроссплатформенное и модифицируемое (легкое в сопровождении) приложение с русским языком это утопия (к сожалению).

Comment: @avp но при этом, какой смысл писать на с++ приложение которое исполняется только в одной среде, и компилируется только одним компилятором, не лучше ли тогда выделить кусок проекта требующий именно С++ в отдельную ветку, а интерфейс, в том числе консольный, горазда легче будет написать на шарпе, яве или другом каком то языке.

Comment: @avp 
1. непонятно как шрифт связан с вопросом о кодировке
2. SetCurrentConsoleFontEx переключит его, msdn гарантирует
3. собственно зачем что-то рассказывать непонятно тем более
4. в предложенном вами способом с CharToOem придется
  a. вручную конвертировать каждый раз, хотя можно единожды установить подходящий фацет для локали
  б. ограничиться только 2мя кодировками

Comment: @Mirdin, да хороший солдат мечтает стать генералом (и это похвально). 

Практически же, изначальное стремление к "абсолютной" кроссплатформенности, повторному использованию кода и т.п. порождает кучу уродцев.

--

IMHO программы просто надо писать так, чтобы те из них, которые на практике оказались полезными, переносились не автоматически, а скажем так, *легко*, с минимальным переписыванием системозависимых частей. 

Я прекрасно понимаю, что это противоречит, как устремлениям манагеров, так и воззрениям профессоров (во многом спонсируемых манагерами), но такова суровая правда жизни.

Comment: @avp причем тут абсолютная кросплатформенность? Если заголовок <windows.h> соседствует с cin, то этот кусок кода надо легче переписать на шарпе, чем вычистить из него системозависимые части.

Comment: @Mirdin конкретно здесь он нужен для управления _консоли_ _Windows_, и призван продемонстрировать совет #2. Кроссплатформенный вариант будет полностью основан на локалях и фацетах. Тут мы балансируем на грани платформозависимости.

Comment: @Dith конкретно здесь, мы имеем новичка ТС, которому вы даете крайне платформозависимый совет. Если ему придется завтра сменить компилятор (заметьте не ос)?

Comment: @Mirdin а какой способ решения можете предложить Вы мне?

Comment: @Mirdin как раз поэтому я даю совет, который заработает у него, и разбирает суть вопроса, а не влазит в рассуждения проблемы переносимости, которые ему совершенно не нужны. Это все отмечено первым комментарием в коде, как раз чтобы не возникало вопросов насчет переносимости. И если он сменит компилятор (да да, даже не ос) то совершенно не почувствует разницу.

Comment: @Dith, вот Ваша программа у меня правильно работает только в случае вызова SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); **но без** SetConsoleCP(1251); (для ввода).

Если делаем вызов setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian_russia.1251"); то все равно выводит кракозябры. (хотя у меня стоит шрифт Lucida Console).

Здесь (на хэшкоде) таких обсуждений было очень много. Не уверен, что есть хоть одно, где приведена 100% работающая во всех окружениях (только винды!, я уж не говорю о других системах) программка.

К сожалению поиск по сайту  работает плоховато.

Comment: >При этом не забываем переключить шрифт в консольном окошке на "Lucida Console". 

>А вот как сделать это программно (и можно ли вообще) не знаю.

Можно, но это платформозависимо, на рубеже `XP`. В `XP` - только через `SetConsoleFont`. Тут придется подобрать нужный номер для `Lucida Console` (сейчас не помню точно, какой тут нужен номер, но его легко подобрать через `GetCurrentConsoleFont` и `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO::nFont`). В более старших - есть `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`, тут все проще: шрифт можно выставить напрямую в `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX::FaceName`.

Comment: >К сожалению поиск по сайту работает плоховато.

Googloпоиск по сайту: <http://www.google.com/search?q=site:hashcode.ru+setlocale+windows>

Comment: @avp Вы уверенны, что это девственная консоль? Раз уж пускаться во все тяжкие, то перед установкой свойств консоли нужно сначала получить её текущие свойства, и уже в зависимости от них устанавливать шрифты/локали. Может все-же сфокусироваться на принципах, которые я хотел передать?

Comment: @Dith, Вы думаете, Вы самый тут умный? Вопрос о кодировке в виндовской консоли обсуждался здесь уже много раз. И все, что Вы сказали, уже было много раз сказано. Считаю, что начинающему не нужно всем этим забивать голову, а сосредоточиться на более важных вещах, чем кривости отдельно взятой системы.

По поводу Вашего выступления на вопросе @avp про Boost я уже написал про юникод в Линуксе. Считаю, что Ваше замечание было совсем не в кассу. Если можете предложить решение той проблемы без помощи wchar_t - напишите там код **для линукса**.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdio>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,".866");
    int i;
    wchar_t numbers[][81] = { L"Санёк", L"24567", L"Брат", L"23145", L"Мама", L"25674", L"Папа", L"26475", L"Любимая", L"24534"}, name[81];
    wcout << L"Введите имя: ";
    wcin >> name;
    for (i=0; i<10; i+=2)
    {
        if (!wcscmp(name,numbers[i]))
        {
            wcout << L"Телефон " << name << L": " << numbers[i+1] << L"\n";
            break;
        }

    }
    if (i >= 10)
    {
        wcout << L"Ничего не найдено\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если мне не изменяет память функции str* не любят языки отличные от английского.

Comment: Функции str* не могут любить *wchar_t, поскольку они там быстро найдут нулевой символ. С utf-8 таких проблем быть не должно.

Comment: а причем тут wchar_t к функциям str. Я говорю о том что разные реализации могут "очень по разному" работать с языками отличными от английского в виде символов char.

Comment: Странно, коли тема давно избита, почему старожилы сразу не дали ссылку на правильный ответ.

Comment: @Dith, видимо старожилам просто надоело бесплодно предлагать разные способы и спорить об простоте их использования и переносимости.

А Вы знаете правильный ответ?